# Discord - CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Can someone tell me what I did wrong? I'm getting a error saying "CLIENT_MISSING_INTENTS". I'm not exactly sure what this means and I tried to look it up and the only thing I found was to install node.js, which I have installed, do I need to install it to Visual Studio Code, or something like that?

**index.js:**

```
const bot = new Discord.Client({ disableEveryone: true });
const botconfig = require("./botconfig.json");
const fs = require("fs");

bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
bot.aliases = new Discord.Collection();

// Read Commands Folder
fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) =>{ 
    if(err) console.log(err);

    let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
    if(jsfile.length <= 0) {
        console.log("Couldn't find any commands!")
        return;
    }

    jsfile.forEach((f) => {
        let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);
        console.log(`${f} loaded!`);
        bot.commands.set(props.help.name, props);

        props.help.aliases.forEach(alias => {
            bot.alias.set(alias, props.help.name);
        })
    })
})

// Bot Online Message And Activity Message
bot.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online on ${bot.guilds.size} servers!`);
    bot.user.setActivity(`with ${bot.guilds.size} servers!`)
})

bot.on("message", async message => {
    
    // Check Channel Type
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    // Set Prefix
    let prefix = botconfig.prefix;

    // Check Prefix, Define Args & Command
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ */g);
    let cmd;
    cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    let command;
    let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd.slice(prefix.length));
    if(commandfile) commandfile.run(bot, message, args);

    // Run Commands
    if(bot.commands.has(cmd)) {
        command = bot.commands.get(cmd);
    } else if (bot.aliases.has(cmd)) {
        command = bot.commands.get(bot.aliases.get(cmd));
    }
    try {
        command.run(bot, message, args);
    } catch (e) {
        return;
    }
})

bot.login(botconfig.token)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Add intents to client

As of the v13 update, you must include an array of intents that your bot can use.

For example:

```js
const bot = new Discord.Client({
  intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"],
  disableEveryone: true
});
```

A more detailed explanation is given on the official djs guide https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html

#### If it's your first bot

Open up https://discord.com/developers/applications and head to your application's page. Navigate to the "Bot" tab down the left and scroll a bit. Enable both of the "Privileged Gateway Intents"

This is optional but it will allow you to receive certain events which are otherwise not accessible.

Comment: You don't have to add Intents in discord.js v12, they were only added in v13

Comment: Intents were added in v12...

Comment: There is only one thing I found about "intents" in v12 changelogs: `Document intent error code messages (f4b1b39)`, so I'm really interested in how they were added in v12 cuz I was able to run my code without them on this version =3

Comment: @PiggyPlex intents were added in v12, but were only required in v13

Comment: @MrMythical https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Intents

Comment: *"but were only required in v13"* - @PiggyPlex

Comment: where's that? @MrMythical

Comment: In my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70050529/discord-client-missing-intents/70050758?noredirect=1#comment123838581_70050758) above - you don't get any error for not specifying intents